# Effectively parse single-element JSON in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is the situation: in **Objective-C**, I'm fetching **JSON** data from my server. I know for sure (and it won't change) that my JSON data only contains one JSON element named token that is a string. It will look like this :

```
{
    "token": "ertvgbyhnujk45678CVBNkjuhgfvgb"
}
```

What's the way to just get the token string value? **It's probably very easy but I'm totally new to Objective-C.**

Comment: use like ***yourDictionaryName[@"token"]***, at the same time show your tried code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

`NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];`

Then get the token by using: `dictionary[@"token"]`.

The error parameter in the method above can be nil because you said you're sure that it won't change and it'll always be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *token = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil][@"token"];
```